# Tag-post relationship problem

Tags: custom-post-types, tags

tag is not working in wordpress like it is supposed to.
When I add tag to a custom post type it shows up in tags list and the relationship can be seen in the `term_relationships` table and the tags are seen in the posts when I edit the page.But the post count for tag remains zero and the link of the tag does not give me the posts related to the tags.For example

```
mysite.com/tag/mytags
```

does not give me the posts related to this tag.

I have tried this manually as in i have used these also wp_insert_term and wp_set_post_term and the problem is same.
this problem is only when I use custom post type.But when I use post type:post.This works perfectly.Is there somethig that I am missing?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The URL can vary based on your settings. Do you have a category or tag base set? I believe the default URL of  mytag would go to `mysite.com/mytag`. See more at [the wordpress codex page on permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Category_base_and_Tag_base).

Comment: the url is working  because as I have written above the url is working perfectly for post type post it.I mean when I do      `site.com./tag/mytag` it shows all the post type post related to tags but doesnot show custom post types

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-tagscategories-archive-page

Comment: this is close but not quite what i was looking for the count for the post related to tag doesnot increase in mine.So I don't think it establishes a relation to begin with but the weird thing is the term id and post id both show up in term_relationship but count   doesnot increase in term_taxonomy.i have been hung up on this four more than 5 days now but no solution